# Arc and nilling property through weak pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a situation here where I would want to nil a strong property with a weak reference property. My class looks like this;

```
@interface MyClass()
@property(nonatomic, strong) Man *man;
@property(nonatomic, strong) Women *women;
@property(nonatomic, weak) Person *passedPerson
@end
```

I pass this object everytime to the new view controller, sometimes I pass men while some time I pass women but I always keep track of the passed object in weak reference, ie. passedPerson.
Now, when the viewcontroller return, based on the currently passed object, I would like to nil it through the weak reference pointer. Is it even possible ? This is not my exact situation but I have many objects like this which needs to be nilled out when I finish with them in the presenting view controller. How can this be done ?

Comment: Why don't you keep a strong reference and nil out everything when you no longer need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak reference is used when you need to break a reference cycle. In the example you show, there is no reference cycle. But I assume you want to keep the `passedPerson`.

You could use weak references to `man` and `women` and keep a strong reference on the `passedPerson`. Then you can nil out the `passedPerson` as you are finished with them.